# What should I replace a "Timeout Until" step with when converting a background workflow to a real-time workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow

I have a bunch of background workflows that need to be converted to real-time workflows so that the "Modified By" field doesn't get updated with the workflow owner.  The problem is that a lot of the workflows that need to be converted have a "Timeout Until" step where the workflow waits one minute to run.  These "Timeout Until" steps are necessary, as there are plug-ins and other workflows that need to run first in order for these workflows to run correctly.

I do not believe it is possible to use "Timeout Until" in a real-time workflow.  My question is what should I replace "Timeout Until" with?  I want certain workflows to execute AFTER other workflows, so I need some sort of replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I believe that Timeout Until will not work in a synchronous workflow. Even if it did, using it in that context would be contrary to the notion of a synchronous operation and hamper the user experience.

In light of that, a few thoughts:

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-real-time-workflows), if you create a workflow programmatically, you can set the "rank" to specify when it should run relative to other workflows.

> You can order the execution of plug-ins and real-time workflows within a stage by setting a rank. All plug-ins or real-time workflows with a rank of 1 execute before those with a rank of 2, and so on.

However, I see no way to set this through the UI or Plugin Registration tool. (If anyone knows of a way to do it please let us know.)

Fortunately, we can use child workflows to configure a set of workflows to run in a particular order.

[image: Start Child Workflow]

The basic idea is that the parent workflow will run before the children, and the children will run in their configured order.  [This article](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2017/11/20/tips-for-organizing-workflows-in-dynamics-365/) goes into further detail about it.

Personally, I don't recall having configured any child workflows on a synchronous workflow, so your mileage may vary. I imagine you'll want to be conscious of the potential performance impacts of running a bunch of workflows synchronously.

As you may be aware, configuring the sequence of plugins is straightforward via the Plugin Registration Tool.

[image: execution order]

However, dealing with the interplay of plugins and workflows adds a layer of complexity. You could theoretically use flag fields to trigger whatever plugins and workflows you want, in whatever sequence you want.

As you get into triggering multiple things from one platform event, bear in mind that regardless of what combination you use, the platform will short-circuit your operation if the [plugin depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) hits 8.